# VBA: Extract minutes and hours between 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following list:

```
ID  In                        Out 
A   23.03.2018  08:16:14      23.03.2018  13:56:03
B   23.03.2018  11:16:14      23.03.2018  13:56:03
```

I have to create something like this:

```
ID  In                         
A   23.03.2018  08:17:00      
A   23.03.2018  08:18:00
...
A   23.03.2018  13:55:00      
B   23.03.2018  11:17:00
B   23.03.2018  11:18:00
...
B   23.03.2018  13:55:00
```

To do this, I tried with this code

```
Sub TimeSheet()
Dim timeEntries As Range, entry As Range, startTime As Integer, endTime As Integer, hr As Integer, lastRow As Integer

Set timeEntries = Worksheets("Input").Range("A2:A3")

For Each entry In timeEntries
    startTime = GetHour(entry.Offset(0, 1), "IN")
    endTime = GetHour(entry.Offset(0, 2), "OUT")

    For hr = startTime To endTime

        With Worksheets("Output")
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & lastRow) = entry
            .Range("B" & lastRow) = DateValue(entry.Offset(0, 1)) & " " & TimeSerial(hr, 0, 0)
        End With

    Next hr
Next entry

End Sub

Function GetHour(t As Date, stamp As String) As Date
Dim result As Date

If stamp = "IN" Then
    If Minute(t) = 0 Then
        result = Hour(t)
    Else
        result = Hour(DateAdd("h", 1, t))
    End If
Else
    If Minute(t) = 0 Then
        result = Hour(t)
    Else
        result = Hour(DateAdd("h", -1, t))
    End If

End If

GetHour = result
End Function
```

The columns "In" and "Out" contain each a date and a hour. What I need to do is to look at the hour and minute from "In" and "Out" and count the hours and minutes between them. Each counted hour and minute must be save in a line, like in the second table.
With the code above I can extract only hours, ex  23.03.2018  09:00:00, 10:00:00, 11:00:00  etc. Any idea how I can change the function "GetHour" to also save the minute? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just take the difference?

Comment: @urdearboy I can't- For example, 23.03.2018  08:16:14 and  23.03.2018  13:56:03  will return  09:00:00, 10:00:00 etc. However, I need to start with 08:17:00

Comment: @urdearboy actually the function rounds by hour, but I don't need more to round, only to extract the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do away with your function call entirely and just use `DateDiff` to calculate the number of minutes between each entry, using a `For-Next` loop to iteratively add the minute in the iteration to the `startTime`

```
Option Explicit
Sub TimeSheet()
    Dim timeEntries As Range
    Dim entry As Range
    Dim startTime As Date
    Dim endTime As Date
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim minutes As Long
    Dim m As Long

    Set timeEntries = Worksheets("Input").Range("A2:A3")

    For Each entry In timeEntries
        startTime = entry.Offset(0, 1)
        endTime = entry.Offset(0, 2)

        minutes = DateDiff("n", startTime, endTime)
        With Worksheets("Output")
            For m = 1 To minutes - 1
                lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & lastRow) = entry
                .Range("B" & lastRow) = Format(startTime + (m / 1440), "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:00")
            Next m
        End With
    Next entry
End Sub
```

This produced results:

```
A   23.03.2018 08:17:00
A   23.03.2018 08:18:00
A   23.03.2018 08:19:00
A   23.03.2018 08:20:00
....
A   23.03.2018 13:55:00
B   23.03.2018 11:17:00
B   23.03.2018 11:18:00
B   23.03.2018 11:19:00
B   23.03.2018 11:20:00
....
B   23.03.2018 13:55:00
```